# HTML & CSS issue: How can I increase an image('s) height by hovering over it?

Tags: html, css, facebook, image

Suppose, I have a facebook logo image. This image also works as a link to my facebook profile. Now, I want as soon as a user put the mouse cursor over it, it should increase the height (let's say 3 px).

This is my source code I am working on:

```
   .HTML:

     <div id="find_me_on">

        <p>Find me on:</p><br><a href="https://www.facebook.com/unknownuser"><img src="img/fblogo.png" title="Facebook" id="inc_fb_height" /></a>
        </div


    .CSS:

  #inc_fb_height{
    /*Need help*/
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to just increase the height? You can scale it proportionally with [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don´t waste JavaScript (and especially not jQuery) for those things, you only need CSS:

```
#inc_fb_height {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

#inc_fb_height:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Of course you can also just scale the height with `scale(1, 1.1)`, or `scaleY(1.1)`.

**Although, it would be better to start with a scale factor <1 and set scale to 1 on hover - to avoid blurry pictures.**

Here´s that version with scale3d, so it uses hardware acceleration (not really needed in that case, but #yolo):

```
#inc_fb_height {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 1);
    -o-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 1);
}

#inc_fb_height:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: this is very smart solution, it helped me. Although I just wanted to incease the height, why not accepting such a good suggestion like yours.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting you again! Your trics work only in my localhost. But in my website, in the public server, these transforms /scale property don't work. They just do nothing afetr hovering. If you could get a time please check at the very bottom of my website: http://jabiralfatah.com/

Comment: what browser are you trying with? it works fine for me in IE11 and the latest chrome and firefox. did you try deleting your browser cache?

Comment: alright, glad i could help :) - btw, "ease-out" usually looks better than "ease-in-out", in most animations. i will change it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

USE this fiddle if you want css fix only
http://jsfiddle.net/4wpw6add/4/

```
#inc_fb_height{
height:120px; 
}


#inc_fb_height:hover{
height:124px; 
}
```

USE this fiddle if you can use javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/4wpw6add/5/

```
.img-zoom:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('transition');

    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('transition');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a JS fiddle for this. -- [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/4wpw6add/)

```
 #inc_fb_height:hover{
    height:500px; /* new height*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use what you have:

```
#inc_fb_height{
height:100px; 
}
```

but then add

```
#inc_fb_height:hover{
height:103px; 
}
```

creating a hover property that takes the original and changes it to 3px taller on `mouse hover`

Answer (score 0):

add a hover state to the image:

HTML:

```
<div id="find_me_on">
    <p>Find me on:</p> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/unknownuser"><img src="http://www.insidefacebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/profile-150x150.png" title="Facebook" id="inc_fb_height" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img#inc_fb_height {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
}
img#inc_fb_height:hover {
    height: 153px;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jazztorbs/k3u1dLna/